# CountIf referencing named range and starting on row 3

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a countif formula in a cell on sheet 'B'. So far my formula is:

```
=COUNTIF('Consol List'!R[-3]C[-3]:R[-1]C[-3],""<>0"")-COUNTBLANK('Consol List'!R[-3]C[-3]:R[-1]C[-3])
```

however, I need the **two** `Consol List` ranges to reference a named column of `LastColumn` and the **row** to start at `3` and down to `LR`.

For some reason I can not figure out how to do this. help is appreciated.

the only issue is it is giving an application defined or object defined and I’m not sure why..?

```
"=COUNTIF('Consol List'!" & Range(Cells(3, LastColumn), Cells(LR, LastColumn)).Address(0, 0) & """<>0"")-COUNTBLANK('Consol List'!" & Range(Cells(3, LastColumn), Cells(LR, LastColumn)).Address(0, 0) & ")"
```

Comment: there's not actually "quotes" around it, right?

Comment: no theres no quotes around them

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use R1C1 notation?

Comment: no, that was just there from recording the macro. The 'lastcolumn' will be changing based on the array iteration though and it will always be row 3 to LR

Comment: Gotcha.  Just learning VBA?  Recording macros was how I first taught myself too.  Which cells do you need to count? `Consol List` is a named range, right? Or is that the name of the worksheet?

Comment: no - that is just a place holder. LastColumn is the named range for column and LR is the last row with values so it would countif from row 3 to LR as the range

Comment: wouldn't your original formula be better as `=COUNTIFS('Consol List'!R[-3]C[-3]:R[-1]C[-3], "<>0", 'Consol List'!R[-3]C[-3]:R[-1]C[-3], "<>")`?

Comment: @Jeeped - I dont believe so because the columns are going to be changing based on the array iteration

Comment: I think scott was closest with "=COUNTIF('Consol List'!" & Range(Cells(3, LastColumn), Cells(LR, LastColumn)).Address(0, 0) & """<>0"")-COUNTBLANK('Consol List'!" & Range(Cells(3, LastColumn), Cells(LR, LastColumn)).Address(0, 0) & ")" the only issue is it is giving an application defined or object defined error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use A1 notation:

```
"=COUNTIF('Consol List'!" & Range(Cells(3,LastColumn),Cells(LR,LastColumn)).Address(0,0) & ",""<>0"")-COUNTBLANK('Consol List'!" & Range(Cells(3,LastColumn),Cells(LR,LastColumn)).Address(0,0) & ")"
```

Comment: That dosnt seem to work, I dont think it is referencing if NOT 0 and NOT blank. it is always coming out with a 0

Comment: Does the formula paste correctly? is it referencing the correct column?

Comment: if I go back to the cell after running the code the formula only shows as: =COUNTIF('Consol List'!Y3:Y5,'Consol List'!Y3:Y5) - the LastColumn position is right though..

Comment: those work too - but the formula is not counting anything other then 0 and removing blanks

Comment: Yeah see the latest edit I missed part of the formula.

Comment: I am now getting an application defined or object-defined error on that line

Comment: The formula you posted in the question and my answer are different, you are missing a `,`.  @Nic